# data migration is triggering a query at import time

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

my last migration was a data migration that Trigger thumbnails update for profile app

```
def trigger_thumbnails_update(apps, schema_editor):
    """
    Trigger thumbnails update for profile app
    """
    User = apps.get_model('profile', 'User')
    for user in User.objects.all():
        if user.photo:
            make_image_thumbnail.delay()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('profile', '0008_auto_20190611_2120'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(trigger_thumbnails_update),
    ]
```

after that, I added a field called `is_daleted`, and run `makemigrations` :

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('profile', '0009_trigger_thumbnails_update'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='user',
            name='is_deleted',
            field=models.BooleanField(default=False),
        ),
    ]
```

that works fine, but when I run tests (pytest) I get that error : `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column profile_user.is_deleted does not exist`

I think that it's caused by my data migration is triggering a query at import time, so it runs before the migration itself.

commenting the triggering code solve the problem temporary, I need a real solution, please

**update** here is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column profile_user.is_deleted does not exist
LINE 1: ...r"."is_onboarded", "profile_user"."last_request", "profile_u...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 385, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 648, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/app/apps/utils/tasks.py", line 18, in make_image_thumbnail
    obj = Model.objects.get(pk=pk)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 393, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 250, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1183, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 54, in __iter__
    results = comp...
```

Comment: It will run the query *before* the second one, because you defined this as a *dependency*.

Comment: where does the function `make_image_thumbnail` come from? You should try not to import functions from model files due to the problem with historical models. When doing data migrations, copy the function code into your data migration code (even if that duplicates the code), that way there can never be an issue later on when you change the function. Migrations code needs to be "static", i.e. never change after the migration was applied.

Comment: Please post the full traceback. But chances are the issue is exactly the one explained by dirkgroten anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migration code is running using [Hostorical model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/#historical-models), this is why you cannot import directly your models, and instead need to get them via `apps.get_model(...)`. When the migration file is executed, it runs with the version of you `User` model at the time of the migration, without the `is_daleted` field.

However, the celery task `make_image_thumbnail` that you call from the migration is NOT using this hostorical model. As far as the task knows, the `User` model has a `is_deleted` field, it uses the latest version of the model, as per your `models.py`.

When you call the task from the first migration, the column doesn't exist yet in the database.

Why is it a problem in test and not when you run the migration manually? Often, I run my tests with [`CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER = True`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-task_always_eager), which might be what you do too. When running tests, your task is executed synchronously inside the first migration. When you executed the migration manually, this was disabled, and your task actually ran after the 2nd migration.

I also agree with @dirkgroten here: I would recommend to copy the code of your task in the migration. If that's too complicated because it uses custom methods or attribute, I would recommend to not do it in a data migration. You have a few options:

- Run the task manually
- You can use a [custom admin command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/)
- Temporarily introduce a [`post_migrate` signal handler](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#post-migrate)

More generally, running a celery task from a migration is a bad idea IMO, and I would advise against it.